# Analysis I (Amann, Escher) I.12 Exercise 1 (vector spaces)

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory, solution-verification

**Exercise:**

> [image]

**Questions and comments:**

I don't understand (a). I know a field over itself is a vector space. There is probably some fact about fields I am overlooking. I assume a subspace of $K$ is just a subfield of $K$, but I don't know much about subfields. I guess the two-element field would be one subspace.

I think I understand (b). I was pretty sure the answer was 2 based on the notion of the complex plane, but proving it seemed finicky, until I looked at Wikipedia and smacked myself on the forehead when I saw that $\{ 1, i \}$ made a lot more sense to work with than some pair $\{ a + bi, c + di \}$ where we assume one is not a scalar multiple of the other. With $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb R$, we can create any complex number through the linear combination $\alpha \cdot 1 + \beta \cdot i$, and $\alpha \cdot 1 + \beta \cdot i = 0$ implies that $\alpha, \beta = 0$ as desired.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $K$ is a dimension $1$ vector space over itself. So the dimension of any subspace is less than or equal to $1$.

Let $V\subset K$ be a subspace. If the dimension of $V$ is $0$, then it must be the trivial subspace. If the dimension is $1$, then it must be spanned by $[u]$ for some $u\in K$. But then $u^{-1} \cdot [u] = [u^{-1}u] =[1] \in U$. So we have $[k] \in U$ for all $k \in K$, and $U = K$ as vector spaces.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're using square brackets to distinguish vectors from scalars, right?

Comment: @Novice you're correct

Comment: I was looking for an argument that made use of properties of fields, but you've done it by just focusing on vector space properties. I guess by your argument, the two-element field would be a subfield if and only if $K$ were originally a two-element field. Seems like a slick argument. Thanks.